# Nginx + gunicorn + django

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Using this stack is giving me problems with django compressor and less static files. If I run the django dev server behind nginx there is no problem. If I try gunicorn, I get errors from gunicorn saying it can't find the less files. Why would gunicorn be looking for static files?

Comment: can you post your errors? can you post your nginx and gunicorn and django configs?

Comment: Your nginx configuration will help too. It sounds like you are passing requests for static files onto gunicorn instead of serving them via nginx

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow map the static files in gunicorn, too. In uwsgi the directive would be

```
static-map /static=/var/www/your-project/static
```

I think the problem is that Gunicorn cannot access the static files itself, because the routes do only exist at the Nginx level. You have to tell it where the files are.